# Visual Studio 2010 project displays a weird name under VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I created a project and solution in Visual Studio 2010 for a VC++ MFC application, and added quite a bit of code there. Then, today, I opened the same project in Visual Studio 2013. I set the following property

```
Platform Toolset : Visual Studio 2013 (v120)
```

Strangely, the project's name got changed from **MyProject** to **MyProject (Visual Studio 2010)**

Between, the v120 in project properties and the Visual Studio 2010 in the name, I am a little confused. Does it mean I have all the capabilities of Visual Studio 2010 or 2013?

Comment: i think its showing the round trip of the project files.

Comment: @DanielA.White, could you please elaborate? I did not get what you meant by the round trip.

Comment: v120 is the toolset (compiler linker etc.) used to compile your project - v120 is the default for VS2013. You can change it in Project->Properties->General Platform Toolset. I **think** you need to use the same toolset to compile all your projects/lib/dlls that ship together.